# What is the purpose of inheriting the RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) class in android studio (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I would like to know the purpose of inheriting the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)` class for the **recycler view** in Android Studio. The `RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)` doesn't seem to have a purpose other than accepting `view` as an argument. Unlike **RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>()** where I was required to override some methods..

```
class ItemAdapter(
private val context: Context,
private val dataset: List<Affirmation>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

class ItemViewHolder(private val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_title)
}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
    
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
    
}


override fun getItemCount() = dataset.size
}
```

Comment: Because they're managed by the `RecyclerView` and its `Adapter` and have a bunch of methods and internal state to enable that: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Comment: There are many useful things that one can do with a [RecyclerView.ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder). Take a look at the documentation and you will see the public methods and fields that you can use. The extension makes those available to you and to the _RecyclerView_.